# Maven - Unable to resolve dependencies

Tags: maven, nexus

Im trying to compile a Maven project. The compile fails however due to a `"Failure to find xx.xxx.jar"` in the repository i have specified in my `settings.xml`. I have access to this repository and when i navigate to the Url of the repository maven is trying to use i can see a pom file with the name of the jar but no jar. When i open the pom it contains the correct groupid and artificatid and jar name however the jar is not in the same directory.

Maven gives another error saying that `"resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of my repo-server has elasped or updated are forced"`.

What is happening here? 
When maven goes to the repo i specify in `settings.xml` and finds a pom for the jar does it then try and go out to some external site to resolve the dependency or should the jar exist in the same folder as the pom?

Comment: The jar should exist in the same directory as the pom file if the packaging of the pom is really jar.  Take a look at the pom file in that directory.  What is the packaging on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What module are you attempting to download?

I discovered something similar with the following Maven central module:

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|net.sf.json-lib|json-lib|2.4|jar

The Maven POM **packaging** declaration was *jar*, but no jar in Maven called "json-lib-2.4.jar"

When I looked at the files actually stored, I discovered that the author is providing two versions of the jar, each compiled for different versions of the JVM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <classifier>jdk13</classifier>    
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <classifier>jdk15</classifier>    
</dependency>
```